# Relay circuit with MOC3021 and BT136

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, triac, snubber

I am designing a relay circuit with MOC3021 and BT136 from this [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/97984.pdf).
[image]

I know the importance of snubber circut(39ohm resistance and 0.01uf capacitor). But I have no idea why 360,470 ohm resistance and 0.05uF cap is required (may be low pass filter). what its importance ?

Any article/blog is also helpful.

PS: I refereed many blogs but they are only explaining the importance of snubber circuit

Comment: The answer reads in the datasheet, in the text below that picture.

Comment: " 470 ohm resistor and 0.05 µF capacitor are for snubbing the coupler", buy why we need snubber for opto-coupler ? Not found any blog that explaining the  importance of snubber ckt with opto-copler.

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia Think about the load. Resistive is too easy. So ignore that. But suppose the load is highly inductive. Find the following sentence, "unwanted turn-ons can be avoided by using a snubber circuit," in [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC). That's the area titled "Snubber circuits." Then also read the section just above it, called "Commutating dv/dt and di/dt." All very much worth a read.

Comment: @jonk agree with your thoughts and understand the req of snubber circuit(39ohm and 0.01uF cap) But i am asking for T ckt use in between opto and BT136(360,470 ohm and 0.05uF cap).

Comment: This app note describes your circuit: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3003.pdf.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you have a resistive load, you only need one resistor in series with the triac. R1 is chosen for the minimum line voltage at which you require the triac to turn-on. 10V might be a typical specification, this means that you can never get 180 degrees conduction, the triac isn't guaranteed to turn-on until you have met the minimum gate current. Note that for most conduction angles, R1 only conducts a large current momentarily, when the triac turns on, the voltage is reduced to about 0.7V.

For an inductive load, you need to hold the gate current until current flows in the triac (M1-M2). The inductive load will cause the M1-M2 current to lag. C2 is chosen to hold the gate current long enough for the M1-M2 current to meet the minimum hold current. Note that loads are rarely purely inductive. The value of R4 needs to be low enough so the voltage on C2 follows the line fairly closely.

onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3003.pdf.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqhbtX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The Opto T=RC=18us is permits some attenuation of glitches created by EMI on a long line between controller and IR diode from false triggering DIAC and 2nd stage TRIAC.

More important function might be to permit lower dimming range on a Halogen or incandescent bulb.  Since these have a large PTC effect, they have ~ 10% of the hot resistance which requires more gate current to trigger for the Triac which is harder when the hFE of Triac BJT’s are near saturation or very low phase angle of this non-zero crossing Opto drive with respect to the line AC voltage.

Imagine that the cap decays down to few volts in the off condition when the OPTO DIAC is triggered from off to the lowest dim setting.  The switch suddenly closes and applies the Cap voltage to discharge into the TRIAC just before the zero crossing so that a very narrow pulse or no pulse can be applied at zero crossing.  All Halogen Triac dimmers have a hysteresis effect due to the PTC effect in the filament. In cheaper commercial designs this often causes a higher dim level with flicker when turning ON than turning down from a higher level.  The DIAC voltage with capacitor discharge permits a better trigger condition for low phase angle in either direction rising or falling phase angles as opposed to a linear LED current into a Triac affected by a nonlinear PTC load.

Without computing the maximum currents at worst case peak voltages, I assume the R values are chosen to limit the power dissipation in both the resistors, DIAC out or TRIAC gate at 90 degrees phase angle when sine voltage is peak yet still meet the TRIAC trigger current at low phase angle.  The Snubber latency delay in the 1st R1C ought not to exceed the discharge T=C(R2+Rgate) so that a low phase angle doesn’t go past 0 and trigger a whole cycle at full power.

Disclaimer: I have never tried this design, but this is what I expect from this and what considerations are important in phase angle control.

Too bad the guru who did this, left out his design specs. One should read Design Engineering magazine user submissions to learn these tricks from the detailed theory of operation, as I did back in EE school in the early ’70’s in the Engineering Library. Now you can find these at archive.org